# adding extra avatar sizes in BuddyPress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm aware that I can add the following to my bp_custom.php file in order to change the sizes that avatars are cropped to.

```
<?php

if ( !defined( 'BP_AVATAR_THUMB_WIDTH' ) )
define( 'BP_AVATAR_THUMB_WIDTH', 50 ); //change this with your desired thumb width

if ( !defined( 'BP_AVATAR_THUMB_HEIGHT' ) )
define( 'BP_AVATAR_THUMB_HEIGHT', 50 ); //change this with your desired thumb height

if ( !defined( 'BP_AVATAR_FULL_WIDTH' ) )
define( 'BP_AVATAR_FULL_WIDTH', 260 ); //change this with your desired full size,weel I changed it to 260 <img src="http://buddydev.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">

if ( !defined( 'BP_AVATAR_FULL_HEIGHT' ) )
define( 'BP_AVATAR_FULL_HEIGHT', 260 ); //change this to default height for full avatar

?>
```

However I need to actually add a third option called 'tiny' with a height/width of 15px while keeping standard thumb and full options intact.

How would I go about this?